# docker diff files fill up /var/lib/docker/overlay2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am running two custom docker images on an Ubuntu Azure VM as part of a docker-compose, which are (currently) built, tagged and deployed on that machine.

Recently, the machine ran out of disk space and an investigation with `df`, `du` and other tools showed that `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` includes 90 GiB of files. About 99% of the occupied space stems from the `/diff` folder within the overlay2 subfolders, which *- if I understand correctly -* tracked file changes, such as 500mb of node_modules or my gradle build caches.

The Dockerfiles look as follows. I do not understand why there are hundreds of subfolders (of image layers?) in overlay2 with the built files that should not be persisted as they are only used in initial layers of the Dockerfile.

**Spring Gradle Backend**

```
FROM gradle:7.3.1-jdk17 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle bootJar

FROM eclipse-temurin:17
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME="application-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
ENV APP_HOME=/home/gradle/src
VOLUME $APP_HOME/logs
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ARG CERT="ApplicationNameSelfSigned.cer"
#copy and import self signed vm certificate
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /home/gradle/src/src/main/resources/ssl/$CERT $APP_HOME
RUN keytool -importcert -file $CERT -alias $CERT -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
#copy app jar
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /home/gradle/src/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","application-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**Angular NPM Frontend**

```
#stage 1
FROM node:18-alpine3.16 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
#stage 2 dev
FROM nginx:1.23.2-alpine as dev
COPY --from=node /app/dist/application-name /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /nginx_azure_dev.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /ssl/. /etc/nginx/ssl/live/application-url.com/
EXPOSE 80 443
```

Pruning the docker system with `docker system prune -a` or similar commands did not free up any space. I stopped all containers and basically removed everything in docker, but the disk space stays occupied. I confirmed that overlay2 is my current storage driver.

What have I set up wrong in my architecture? Is this an intended behavior or how to fix it?